# mysqldump error

Tags: linux, connection, mysql

While taking backup mysqldump I use this command and getting 'too many connection error' on linux

```
$MYSQL_BINDIR_PATH/mysqldump -u$user -p$password -h $host --flush-logs --delete-master-logs --master-data=2 --add-drop-table --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --all-databases | gzip > $BACKUP_PATH/$DBFN && successFlag=1
```

please let me know the solution..

Comment: @JamWaffles, it means I'm not that smart... hahahahha

Comment: Have you tried the full documentation?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check how many connections are open on your db, then check what's the limit on the mysql configuration file
ie: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

command to get current status:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```